# setting editor for crontab -e , why always using basic vim?

Tags: vim, crontab

When issuing `crontab -e` as `root` , i always got messages like the following (partial) , however , executing `vim` directly doesn't have problems at all.
`$EDITOR` was set to `vim` in `/root/.bash_profile` already.

```
%> sudo crontab -e
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line    2:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd! BufNewFile * silent! 0r ~/.vim/skel/tmpl.%:e
line   20:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: autocmd VimEnter * set vb t_vb=
line   57:
E518: Unknown option: autochdir
line   65:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syn on
line   78:
E538: No mouse support: mouse=a
line   79:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: filetype plugin indent on
line   87:
E319: Sorry, the command is not available in this version: funct! CommentBlock(comment)
line   88:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use "sudo command" the root user profile is not loaded, use `sudo -i` and `crontab -e` instead.

Comment: no difference with `sudo -i crontab -e`

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear, you need to: "sudo -i" ENTER, then contrab -e. "sudo -i command" will not load the root's .bashrc, that is why the EDITOR is not being properly set.

Comment: not work as well , also i tried to 'Default env_keep = EDITOR' with visudo , it's still not working , but 'sudo su -' , and then 'crontab -e' works

Comment: *[Running 14.04. Desktop LTS:]* Isn't there a simpler way than `$ sudo -i` followed by `$ crontab -e` followed by choosing yr editor of choice ? It seems that loading root's `.bashrc` when invoking `sudo + cmd` should be accessible to permanent configuration. Should not there be at least an option for that ?

Comment: 12 years later, `sudo -i crontab -e` is exactly the command I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score -1):

in ubuntu-14.04,  use `select-editor` choose "vim-gnome" but not "vim-basic"

Comment: In 16.04 your options are 1. `/bin/ed`, 2. `/bin/nano` (recommended) and 3. `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`.

Comment: The user is using the cli therefore suggesting to use vim-gnome would mean that he'd need the gnome libraries installed. They may not be available.